# Transcription cipher encryption program crashes

Tags: c++

I don't know how to solve it. It does the job, everything looks good, but it crashes at the end of encrypting. 
It might be the last sign.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "This is a sample text that i want to encrypt";
    int d = text.length();
    int n = ceil(sqrt(d));
    string encrypted[n * n];

    int i = 1;
    int pos = 1;

    while(i <= n)
    {
        int j = 0;

        while(j < n)
        {
            encrypted[pos] = text[i + j * n - 1];
            cout << text[i + j * n - 1] << " ";
            pos++;
            j++;
        }

        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        cout << encrypted[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check for out of bounds access, and also `string encrypted[n*n]` is a variable length array which is not supported by the official C++ standard. Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there, where You are requesting such thing:

```
encrypted[pos] = text[i + j * n - 1];
```

where:

- *i* goes to *n*
- *j* goes to *n* and is additionally multiplied by *n*

So, as a result, You are requesting element *n+n*n* of *text*, which is only *d* elements long.
From the above case, index 56 is over 44.

Comment: No, it's going to n + (n-1)*n - 1.  i isn't multiplied by j.